# Adding a Spring Data Module

Tags: spring-data, orientdb

I'd like to publish the OrientDB Spring Data module:

https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb/tree/develop

But the OrientDB team can't publish it, because it's under the Spring package:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
```

What's the procedure to release it on Maven Repository? Should we change the package name? It would be community-driven, but still official?